# Account Compression Proof Changes

Tags: compression, account-compression, das

Do proofs for an asset ID change as more elements are added to Merkle Tree.

If i call getAssetProof via the DAS will the result returned become invalid when more nodes are added to the Tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the proof is dependent on the neighbor nodes and will change every time an NFT is transferred, minted, or updated. However, the concurrent merkle tree architecture tries to minimize hitting stale proofs by storing a buffer of old roots to verify against. Therefore a stale proof can still be used so long as the # of updates after the proof is fetched does not exceed the MAX_BUFFER_SIZE.

For more details on the concurrent merkle tree architecture, take a look at the Metaplex docs.
https://developers.metaplex.com/bubblegum/concurrent-merkle-trees